# trying to update multiple rows in php using checkboxes

Tags: php

I am trying to update multiple values from table via PHP using checkboxes. I am missing something but I have been stuck for hours. What i am doing wrong? Nothing gets updated.

```
<?php

        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    ?>

    <tr>

        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checked_id[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['lead_id']; ?>"/></td>        
        <td><input name="lead_id[]" type="hidden" value= "<?php echo $row['lead_id']; ?>"></td>

        <td><input name="lead_compname[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['lead_compname']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input name="lead_add[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['lead_add']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input name="lead_city[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['lead_city']; ?>"></td>   
        <td><input name="lead_cp[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['lead_cp']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input name="lead_cpd[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['lead_cpd']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input name="lead_cpno[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['lead_cpno']; ?>"></td>   
        <td><input name="lead_cpemail[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['lead_cpemail']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input name="value[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['value']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input name="clodate[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['clodate']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input name="prodtype[]" type="text" value= "<?php echo $row['prodtype']; ?>"></td>



    </tr> 

    <?php } }else{ ?>

        <tr><td colspan="5">No records found.</td></tr> 

    <?php } ?>
```

action file is

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])){

    $idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];

    foreach($idArr as $id){

        mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE leadinfor SET lead_compname='$lead_compname[$id]', lead_add='$lead_add[$id]' WHERE lead_id='$lead_id[$id]'");

    }

    $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Updated successfully.';

    header("Location:upd.php");

}

?>
```

Comment: What doesn't gets updated? The checkboxes, or something else. Please clarify the problem you're having with this code

Comment: Please clarify your problem.

Comment: <?php

session_start();

include_once('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])){

    $idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];

    foreach($idArr as $id){

        mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE leadinfor SET lead_compname='$lead_compname[$id]', lead_add='$lead_add[$id]' WHERE lead_id='$lead_id[$id]'");

    }

    $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Updated successfully.';

    header("Location:upd.php");

}

?>

Comment: <?php

session_start();

include_once('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST['bulk_delete_submit'])){

    $idArr = $_POST['checked_id'];

    foreach($idArr as $id){

        mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE leadinfor SET lead_compname='$lead_compname[$id]', lead_add='$lead_add[$id]' WHERE lead_id='$lead_id[$id]'");

    }

    $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'Updated successfully.';

    header("Location:upd.php");

}

?>

Comment: @Jayashreevenugopal Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38027633/edit) your question with your code addition

Comment: thats my action file...

Comment: i have passed the values in an array from the html table and trying to update the fields all at once

Answer (score 0):

First; sometimes it helps to see just what exactly is being sent. Make use of PHP's debugging functionality.

For example;

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Once you have determined the key/value within the $_POST super global array you can then update your SQL statement accordingly.